# What is the most frequently mentioned proper noun/adjective in Star Trek that remains undepicted?

Tags: star-trek, names, worldbuilding

Part of world-building involves making references to invented objects, people, and races.  And since Star Trek had been going on for seven decades, there's been a lot of it.  Sometimes some of those references even become something of an in-joke and we never see the referent.

I am interested in what's been mentioned the most times without being depicted.

For the purpose of this question, any mention and  variants count as the same proper noun/adjecive.  For example, a mention of Plumbian ale, Plumbians, or the Plumbus home world all count.

Similarly, any on-screen depiction of a Plumbus, a Plumbian ship or the planet Plumbus all invalidate the candidate.

Another proper noun, such as a specific name of a person/alien/entity, would also be valid, if there is such a candidate.

Comment: Probably "God".

Comment: Just to be clear, for the TV series? The movies? The books? The RPG?

Comment: @OrganicMarble - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QkT1-N0VqUc

Comment: Kahless (clones don't count).

Comment: Self sealing stem bolts (a MacGuffin)

Comment: @usee16145658 Self sealing stem bolts have been depicted, you can see images here: https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Self-sealing_stem_bolt

Comment: Does Morn's voice count?

Comment: @FuzzyBoots:   not depicted in one of the mainstream shows or films

Comment: @Valorum:  I am pretty sure that there are depictions of paintings of Kahless.   Anyways, I would say a clone counts anyhow since it still answers the question, What does that character look like?

Comment: @user16145658:  *self-sealing stem bolt* isn't a proper noun anyhow...

Comment: @WiggotheWookie Anything that isn't Morn sitting on a barstool would be a good candidate.

Comment: Would the Eugenics Wars count?

Comment: Would you count appearances in onscreen displays, or just dialogue? Alpha Centauri is mentioned in dialogue in six of the [Trek transcripts on the chakoteya.net site](https://www.google.com/search?q=site:chakoteya.net+%22alpha+centauri%22), but the [memory alpha article on Alpha Centauri](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Alpha_Centauri) indicates there are also a bunch of appearances of the system on visible onscreen maps (and it mentions other episodes without saying whether it's in dialogue or onscreen displays, like the TNG ep "Qpid" which doesn't have it in the chakoteya transcript).

Comment: There's a TNG episode that has Picard learning an honorary welcome message in an insectoid language. They string you along the whole episode then neglect to show the species. They don't even show you the ship! Seriously, bait me with space bugs?! I'm still mad.

Comment: @Hypnosifl: spoken or written words do not count as depiction.  Images do.

Comment: @Derek:   Wouldn't Q as a Eugenics Wars combattant count?  The idea is that we want a reference that isn't depicted at all, not get into some discussion of how much of a war we need to see to qualify as a depiction of it.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't asking about whether text on a display counts as a depiction--rather, I was asking about whether it counts towards the total number of "mentions" for the purposes of deciding what is "most frequently mentioned", or if only dialogue counts as a mention.

Comment: Also, does seeing a human colonist who comes from a given system disqualify that system as "undepicted" even if we never seen a shot from the system itself or from any of its native life-forms. As I mentioned above, we have never seen Alpha Centauri, but in "The Metamorphosis", Kirk identified Zefram Cochrane as being from Alpha Centauri, though later canon established he was originally from Earth (he must have settled in the Alpha Centauri system after inventing the warp drive).

Comment: @Hypnosifl:  Yes, I would say that text on a display counts as a mention.  And I would agree that a human from another system doesn't count as a depiction unless that system is only known for its colonies there.

Comment: [Memory Alpha - Mentioned only in dialogue](https://www.google.com/search?q=inurl%3Ahttps%3A%2F%2Fmemory-alpha.fandom.com%2F+%22mentioned+in+dialogue%22&oq=inurl%3Ahttps%3A%2F%2Fmemory-alpha.fandom.com%2F+%22mentioned+in+dialogue%22&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i58.6037j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

Answer (score 7):

I strongly suspect the answer is

- **The Iconians**

They receive mentions in each of TNG, Voyager, Lower Decks, Discovery and DS9 but are never seen nor depicted, presumably because they went extinct over 200,000 years ago.

Comment: Ugh, don't give the writers any ideas for future time-travel scripts :)

Comment: They do show up as major players in *Star Trek Online*, though finding something that hasn't shown up on-screen *or* been mined by expanded universe authors is going to make the task a lot harder.

Comment: @Withad - I don't really count STO as being part of the Trek canon. It's up there with the marvel comics and the children's prose novels for accuracy to the canon

Comment: The Iconian homeworld (or at least one of their outposts) was depicted in the TNG episode "Contagion"; another outpost was depicted in the DS9 episode "To the Death".

Comment: @Derek - Indeed. And also their fab gateways and various artefacts from their culture. But not the Iconians themselves, as far as I'm aware.

Comment: The [Iconian article on memory alpha](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Iconian) mentions the TNG episode "Contagion" had dialogue about Iconians, what are the other two? Likewise, what's the other DS9 besides "To the Death", and what's the other Voyager besides "Inside Man"?

Comment: @Hypnosifl - My apologies. That was meant to be a running count (e.g. 1, 2, 3, 4) but I jumbled them up. I believe the mentions are as above.

Comment: Got it--so aside from the episodes already mentioned there was also the Discovery episode "The Examples", which episode are you thinking of for "Lower Decks"?

Comment: Sorry, but we have seen the Iconian homeworld and an Iconian outpost.  I thought I was pretty explicit in the question that seeing the Iconian homeworld but not seeing an Iconian person does not qualify as an answer.

Comment: @ThePopMachine - But we've never seen an Iconian, just looked around their stuff. We've never even seen a depiction of them

Comment: @Valorum:   I literally wrote:  *Any on-screen depiction of a Plumbus, a Plumbian ship or the planet Plumbus all invalidate the candidate.*

Comment: For anyone who stumbles upon this, the 1/2 bounty was auto-assigned to this because it's the only answer and I was too busy to intervene in time.  It should not be taken as any evidence against that I am explicitly stating that this answer is invalid.

Answer (score 7):

Captain [Boday](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Boday), a Gallamite with a notably transparent skull is mentioned in five episodes of *Deep Space Nine* but is never seen, nor have we ever seen a Gallamite ship or planet, nor any other member of his species.

He's referenced in:

- *DS9: The Maquis, Part I*
- *DS9: Till Death Do Us Part*
- *DS9: Let He Who Is Without Sin...* (3 times)
- *DS9 Penumbra* (6 times)
- *DS9: Resurrection.* (5 times)

That's a total of 17 mentions.

Comment: Getting better....

Comment: Has the Prime Directive ever been depicted? :D

Comment: @DavidW - Only in its absence. Picard talked about it a lot

Comment: There is also the alien in DS9 that is a member of Starfleet who is only mentioned and never seen. Jake Sisko baby sat for them and O'Brien made a birthing pool or something

Comment: @A.Steer - That would be Ensign Vilix'Pran. Mentioned three times; DS9:Heart of Stone, DS9: Apocalypse Rising and (possibly) in DS9: Business as Usual (referred to as "Ensign Pran")

Comment: Don't forget about Greskrendtregk

Comment: @ThePopMachine - Sure, but by the rules of your little game, we see his race, his race's ships and his home planet; https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Ktarian

Comment: @Valorum:  The rules refer to the proper noun itself.  If someone mentions person human Valorum twenty times, you are not eliminated just because we have seen other humans.   (Assuming you are indeed human.)